# Where can I put a Django custom template tag to get it used by a customised Django admin template?

Tags: django-templates, django-admin

I have a customised version of `base-site.html` which is kept in `templates/admin`.

I would like to use a custom template tag in `base-site.html`.

Normally I would put a custom template tag in a `templatetags` package within an app.

In this case, the template is rendered for the admin app, which is outside of my source tree.

Where should I put a custom template tag, so that the admin app uses it when rendering my custom `base-site.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the custom template tag in with all the application custom template tags and it worked without any trouble.